# NullPointerException while writing from Spark to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, azure-databricks, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.0-s_2.11 to write data from spark to Cassandra on Databricks cluster.

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException while writing data from Spark to Cassandra. This is working fine with few records.

But getting issue when I try to load **~150 Million** records.

Can someone help me in finding the root cause?

Here is the code snippet:

```
val paymentExtractCsvDF = spark
                          .read
                          .format("csv")
                          .option("header", "true")
                          .load(/home/otl/extract/csvout/Payment)

    paymentExtractCsvDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- BAN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ENT_SEQ_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PYM_METHOD: string (nullable = true)

case class Payment(account_number: String, entity_sequence_number: String, payment_type: String)
val paymentResultDf = paymentExtractCsvDF.map(row => Payment(row.getAs("BAN"),
        row.getAs("ENT_SEQ_NO"),
        row.getAs("PYM_METHOD"))).toDF()

var paymentResultFilterDf = paymentResultDf
                            .filter($"account_number".isNotNull || $"account_number" != "")
                            .filter($"entity_sequence_number".isNotNull || $"entity_sequence_number" != "")

paymentResultFilterDf
  .write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .mode("append")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "cassandratable", "keyspace" -> "cassandrakeyspace"))
  .save()
```

here is the exception I am getting:

```
Failed to write statements to cassandrakeyspace.cassandratable. The
latest exception was
  An unexpected error occurred server side on /10.18.15.198:9042: java.lang.NullPointerException

Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information

    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(TableWriter.scala:243)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(TableWriter.scala:241)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:241)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:210)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:145)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:210)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:197)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:183)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/11/22 01:12:17 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 1095
19/11/22 01:12:17 INFO Executor: Running task 39.1 in stage 21.0 (TID 1095)
19/11/22 01:12:17 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 77 non-empty blocks including 10 local blocks and 67 remote blocks
19/11/22 01:12:17 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 7 remote fetches in 3 ms
19/11/22 01:12:17 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 64 non-empty blocks including 8 local blocks and 56 remote blocks
19/11/22 01:12:17 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 7 remote fetches in 1 ms
19/11/22 01:12:17 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 1012)
```

Comment: Can you look at the logs in the executor. It will give you more information as the database writes happen directly from the executor.

Comment: Thanks Jayadeep for reply. I looked at executor logs, I can see only above information on all executors. I can also see ,java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to cassandrakeyspace.cassandratable. The
latest exception was
  [/10.11.38.12:9042] Connection has been closed

Comment: You might want to check spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms parameter to see if there are timeouts that are happening on the cassandra database. The other option would be to batch the loads into smaller chunks.

Comment: Just wondering why "Null pointer exception"?. Can you elaborate batch the loads?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your dataframe has key fields with null values. The problem might be in you filter condition. I think you want to do something like this:

```
 var paymentResultFilterDf = paymentResultDf
                        .filter($"account_number".isNotNull && $"account_number" != "")
                        .filter($"entity_sequence_number".isNotNull && $"entity_sequence_number" != "")
```